# Java Applet ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, html, applet

I am trying to make a simple Applet, and it is proving far more challenging than I expected.

I have the following, very basic applet:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class HelloWorldApplet extends Applet
{
   public void paint (Graphics g)
   {
      g.drawString ("Hello World", 25, 50);
   }
}
```

created in notepad and saved as:

**`HelloWorldApplet.java`**

then in the same folder I have the following HTML file:

```
<html>
<title>The Hello, World Applet</title>
<hr>
<applet code="HelloWorldApplet.class" width="320" height="120">
If your browser was Java-enabled, a "Hello, World"
message would appear here.
</applet>
<hr>
</html>
```

created in notepad and saved as:

**`HelloWorldApplet.html`**

I am getting the following **error** when trying to load the page:

```
ClassNotFoundException

HellowWorldApplet.class
```

Java is installed on the machine and from all the tutorials and reading I have done, everything is exactly correct.

Any ideas??

Comment: How did you compiled your code?

Comment: @manish I havent it is all done in notepad

Comment: u have to compile it in order to get .class file. open cmd prompt if using win or terminal in linux like OS. go to the file location using cd and then compile using  javac "filename". It will create a .class file in your current directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embed the following code in the applet file as a multiline comment.

Eg:

```
/*
<applet code="HelloWorldApplet.class" width="320" height="120"></applet>
*/
```

save this as "**HelloWorldApplet.html**"

Compile using `javac` command

**javac HelloWorldApplet.java**

for Run the program using `appletviewer` command

**appletviewer HelloWorldApplet.html**